# Warnings when creating a 9x9 grid of ComboBoxes

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I'm very new to QT, and have just started learning how to create GUIs with Widgets. I'm currently trying to create a 9x9 grid of ComboBoxes using a QGridLayout and a QWidget for the main window. I used a couple of nested for loops to create the grid, as follows:

```
#include "window.h"
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 800;
Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    resize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setWindowTitle("Grid");
    QGridLayout* gl = new QGridLayout;

    QComboBox* sel[81];
    for(int i = 0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<9;j++)
        {
            sel[(i*9)+j] = new QComboBox;
            gl->addWidget(sel[(i*9)+j],i,j,0);
            sel[(i*9)+j]->show();
        }
    }
    this->setLayout(gl);
}
```

The code works, but I get a lot of Geometry warnings, and the window also takes some time to appear:
[image]

This looks a lot like I'm doing something very wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I was setting the layout of the Window widget after adding all the comboboxes, which caused all the comboboxes to be added to the window before being laid out. This messed up the geometry of the window, causing it to be 81 comboboxes long, and resulting in the warnings. Moving the `this->setLayout(gl)` line to before the `for` loops solved the problem.

Comment: Just FYI but... if you remove `sel[(i*9)+j]->show()` that might also fix the problem (the geometry is probably calculated as a side effect of the calls to `show`).